# Google structured data - images with multiple aspect ratios 1:1, 16:9 and 4:3

Tags: json, seo, json-ld

How to handle multiple image sizes?

In the `Organization` I have the same image with three different aspect ratios: `1:1`, `16:9`, `4:3`

How is the correct way to add them in the JSON Linked Data format?

```
{
    "@type": "Organization",
    "image": [{
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 900,
        "url": "https://domain/img_16_9.png"
    },{
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 1200,
        "url": "https://domain/img_1_1.png"
    }]
}
```

I have the same in the `Product` property. How to add the same image to each product but in three different aspect ratios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same image in different aspect ratios for multiple products, you can use the same approach as with the Organization schema and create an array of `ImageObject` for each product with the corresponding aspect ratios:

```
{
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Product Name",
  "description": "Product description",
  "image": [
    {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://domain/img_16_9.png",
      "width": 1200,
      "height": 675
    },
    {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://domain/img_4_3.png",
      "width": 1200,
      "height": 900
    },
    {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://domain/img_1_1.png",
      "width": 1200,
      "height": 1200
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the `width` and `height` properties should correspond to the dimensions of the respective image, and not necessarily to the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this:

```
"image":{
"@type":"ImageObject",
"url":[
"https://example.com/img/name/1x1/view.jpg",
"https://example.com/img/name/4x3/view.jpg",
"https://example.com/img/name/16x9/view.jpg"
],
"contentUrl":"https://example.com/img/name/viewHD.jpg",
"width":"1920",
"height":"1730"
}
```